# how to convert timespan to string with format

Tags: c#

I have timespan "1.00:00:11" and I would like to convert this to string:
"24:00" .As the code

```
DateTime date1 = Convert.ToDateTime("2014/12/12 14:37:56");
DateTime date2 = Convert.ToDateTime(("2014/12/13 14:37:59");
string minutes = (date2.Subtract(date1).TotalMinutes).ToString();
string result = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(minutes)).ToString();
```

I got result = "1.00:00:11".
How to change this result to (HH:mm).

And then I have a problem when I convert the string "24:00" to Datetime.
The Problem is:
The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.

Is there some function?

Comment: Insert code. And format your question properly.

Comment: just get the number of days before the ".". Then split on the rest on ":" and there you have total hours and total minutes

Comment: "And then I have a problem when I convert the string "24:00" to Datetime." That's because "24:00" is not a valid time of day. The hour must be 00, 01 ... 23. It must not be 24.

Comment: If you really got a result of 11 seconds, I think you first need a new CPU for your computer.

Answer (score 0):

To get the amount of time in hh:mm:ss format, you could do something as like,

```
    DateTime date1 = Convert.ToDateTime("2014/12/12 14:37:56");
    DateTime date2 = Convert.ToDateTime(("2014/12/13 14:37:59"));
    double totalSec = date2.Subtract(date1).TotalSeconds;
    string result = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", totalSec / 3600, (totalSec / 60) % 60, totalSec % 60);
```

And this produces the quantity of time in hh:mm:ss format, it is not hh:mm:ss part of any specific day.
So you cannot directly convert it into datetime type. For datetime type max of hh:mm:ss is just 23:59:59.

To get the hh:mm:ss part of the timespan you can do this,

```
    string result = date2.Subtract(date1).ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");
```

Hope this helps...